# Duplicating Directory Trees

Tags: c, c99

For some reason when I run this code the files are not properly copied from the source to the destination directory.  The syntax is: `./a.out source destination`.  Any help is much appreciated!

The utility is used to duplicate a directory tree. It duplicates the entire tree rooted at src-dir into the destination directory rooted at dest-dir. Because it is not used to synchronize directories in the classic sense, the algorithm used to duplicate data from src-dir is a bit unusual.

Both directory trees must exist. If either src-dir or dest-dir do not exist,the program will terminate and print a message indicating the error.
Entities that exist in dest-dir that do not exist in src-dir are left untouched. This means that it doesn’t destroy anything in dest-dir; it just adds or replaces items in dest-dir by copying them from src-dir.

If it encounters an item in src-dir that does not exist in dest-dir, it is copied into dest-dir. This includes files, directories, and subdirectories.

If it encounters a directory (or subdirectory) in src-dir that exists in dest-dir, it will recurse into that directory to continue the duplication process. If it encounters a file in src-dir that exists in dest-dir, the default behavior is to compare the sizes of the files and copy the file in question if the file sizes differ. No comparison of file access or creation times is performed during this check. If the two files differ in size, this will result in the file being copied from src-dir into dest-dir.

```
/*                                                                                                                     
 * Usage: ddup (-argument) (-argument) (-argument) (-argument) src-dir dest-dir                                        
 * Note: Arguments may or may not be used, but must be entered in the above format.                                    
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void copyDir(char *srcPass, char *dstPass);

bool F = false;
bool V = false;
bool b = false;
bool c = false;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int i;
  unsigned char buffer[4096];
  char *srcPath = argv[argc - 2];
  char *dstPath = argv[argc - 1];

  //Scans the input for arguments and marks them as true if they exist                                                 
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
      if (argv[i][1] == 'F') {
        F = true;
      }
      else if (argv[i][1] == 'V') {
        V = true;
      }
      else if (argv[i][1] == 'b') {
        b = true;
      }
      else if (argv[i][1] == 'c') {
        c = true;
      }
    }
  }

  if (V == true) {
    printf("Source Directory: %s\nDestination Directory: %s\n", srcPath, dstPath);
  }

  copyDir(srcPath, dstPath);
}

void copyDir(char *srcPass, char *dstPass) {
  DIR *src = opendir(srcPass);
  DIR *dst = opendir(dstPass);

  struct dirent *dir;
  struct stat buff;

  if (V == true) {
    printf("Contents of the Directory: \n");
  }

  if (src && dst) { //Checks if the src and dst directories exist                                                      

  while ((dir = readdir(src)) != NULL) {

    char ch;
    char newDst[128];

    if (V == true) {
      printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
    }

    stat(dir->d_name, &buff);
    if(S_ISREG(buff.st_mode)) {

      FILE *fPtr1, *fPtr2;

      //Open the first file for reading                                                                                
      fPtr1 = fopen(dir->d_name, "r");
      if (fPtr1 == NULL) {
        if (V == true) {
          printf("Cannot Open File to Read: %s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
        exit(0);
      }
      else {
        if (V == true) {
          printf("Successfully Opened File to Read: %s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
      }

      //Open the second file for writing                                                                               
      strcpy(newDst, dstPass);
      strcat(newDst, "/");
      strcat(newDst, dir->d_name);
      printf("%s", newDst);
      fPtr2 = fopen(newDst, "w");
      if (fPtr2 == NULL) {
        if (V == true) {
          printf("Cannot Open File to Write: %s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
        exit(0);
      }
      else {
        if (V == true) {
          printf("Successfully Open File to Write: %s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
      }

      //Read contents from the file
      ch = fgetc(fPtr1);
      while (ch != EOF) {
        fputc(ch, fPtr2);
        ch = fgetc(fPtr1);
      }

      if (V == true) {
        printf("The file was successfully coppied!");
      }

      fclose(fPtr1);
      fclose(fPtr2);
    }
  }

  closedir(src);
  closedir(dst);
  }
  else {
    printf("Error: Either the source directory or the destination directory do not exist.\n");

    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: You created a full path for the second file, but not for the first file.

Comment: It's not the reason for your problem, but `c` should be declared `int`, not `char`.

Comment: to be able to use `bool`, `false`, and `true`; which are not defined in the C language, you need to include the`stdbool.h` header file

Comment: Please make each indent level 4 spaces.  A mere 2 spaces does not properly show up when using variable width fonts

Comment: the function: `main()` makes the assumption that the user did enter all the expected command line parameters.  The code should be checking the value in `argc` to assure the needed command line parameters were actually entered.  And if they were not entered, the output a `usage` statement to `stderr` and exit

Comment: Variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Variable names like `F`, `V`, `b`, `c` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: the `main()` function sets the local variables: `F` `V` `b` `c`.  Those variables are not visible outside of the `main()` function, nor are they passed to the sub function: `copyDir()`  So why bother to have them at all?

Comment: regarding: `printf("Cannot open file %s\n", dir->d_name);`  when a call to a system function (like `fopen()`) fails, the code should output to `stderr` some text and the text reason the function failed.  Suggest using: `perror()` to perform this action.

Comment: some logic problems in `copyDir()`   1) will copy `,` and `..` which it should not.  2) does not recurse into sub directories.

Comment: regarding: `c = fgetc(fPtr1);
                while (c != EOF)
                {
                    fputc(c, fPtr2);
                    c = fgetc(fPtr1);
                }`  this will be extremely slow, Suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error: Either the source directory or the destination directory do not exist.\n");`  the function: `printf()` is very expensive in CPU cycles,  Suggest using: `puts()`

Comment: Finally I was able to make things somewhat work.  However, the files were copied from odd directories and placed in odd spots...

Comment: Your code is not pure standard C11, but probably POSIX or Linux (so should be tagged as such), since directories are not in the C11 standard (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). You could be interested in [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html). You should compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), improve your code to get no warnings, then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your buggy program

Comment: You might also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) done by your program.

Comment: @user3629249: no need to replace `printf` by `puts` since with `gcc -O` the compiler would nearly do that; in practice a constant `printf` is as fast as a `puts`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch,  I made no assumption that the OP would be passing any of the optimize parameters to the compile and link statements.  passing an optimization parameters would be a mistake on the part of the OP, as it would be difficult enough for the OP to use a debugger (like GDB) with out having to search around for missing/moved code statements

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code. Here are the main issues:

- You stat the source file with `stat(dir->d_name, &buff);` This will only work if the `srcPass` is the current directory. You should instead construct the name of the source file before trying to stat and open it, preferably by allocating a new string to avoid path length issues. Note also that you must check the return value of `stat`: the contents of the stat buffer is meaningless if the file does not exist.
- You read bytes from the stream into a `char` variable `ch`. You must make this an `int` variable to allow proper detection of the end of file condition.
- You should give your global variables more explicit names. Global variables with single character names like `c` are very confusing and error prone.
- You initialize the source and destination paths from `argv[argc - 2]` and `argv[argc - 1]` before testing the number of argument passed. Invoking your program without command line arguments will access `argv[-1]` which has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

the `main()` function can be reduced to:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if( argc == 3 )
    {
        printf("Source: %s, Destination: %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
        copyDir( argv[1], argv[2] );
    }

    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <srcPath> <destPath>\n", argv[0] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the code should be checking for the existence of both directories before beginning to copy the contents of one directory to the other.

If the destination directory does not exist, need to call (in linux) `mkdir()` to assure the destination directory actually exists
`